# Select 3 elements using XPath with namespace but filter it by attribute (Firefox Only)

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd, namespaces

I've got a [Blog structure XML](http://familiagrissi.com/blog/blog.xml) with namespaces. I don't have any problem [printing all the posts title, date and content](http://www.familiagrissi.com/blog/) - Although it only works properly on Firefox (only tested on version 35).

My plan is to add a **select** tag so the user can filter the posts by language. I've  tried **many** different things but none of them worked. Not sure if a browser limitation or wrong coding.

Here are the three main files:

- [blog.xml](http://familiagrissi.com/blog/blog.xml)
- [author.xsd](http://familiagrissi.com/blog/authors.xsd)
- [blog.xsd](http://familiagrissi.com/blog/blog.xsd)
- [posts.xsd](http://familiagrissi.com/blog/posts.xsd)

Although you can see my [source code here](http://www.familiagrissi.com/blog/), here is the main JS method:

```
    function LoadXMLWithXPath() {                           // load post titles and content using XPath
        xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc();                              // get XML content
        var xml = xmlDoc.responseXML;

        var path = "//p:title|//p:content|//p:date";                 // get all titles and its content
        var addContent = "";

        if (typeof xml.evaluate !== 'undefined') {          // if XML is not null. Enough for most browsers.


            /*
             *  xml.evaluate ( xpathExpression, contextNode, namespaceResolver, resultType, result )
             */
            var result = xml.evaluate(path, xml,            // 'result' is a XPathResult object
             function (prefix) {
                 switch (prefix) {                          // namespace resolver
                     case 'b': return 'http://www.familiagrissi.com/blog';
                     case 'a': return 'http://www.familiagrissi.com/authors';
                     case 'p': return 'http://www.familiagrissi.com/posts';
                     default: null;
                 }
             }, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);

            var nodes = xml.evaluate(path, xml,
             function (prefix) {
                 switch (prefix) {
                     case 'b': return 'http://www.familiagrissi.com/blog';
                     case 'a': return 'http://www.familiagrissi.com/authors';
                     case 'p': return 'http://www.familiagrissi.com/posts';
                     default: null;
                 }
             }, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);

            var result = nodes.iterateNext();               // store the nodes content on the result object

            title = true;
            date = false;
            content = false;

            hr = 0;

            testing = "";

            while (result) {
                if (hr % 3 == 0) {
                    addContent += '';
                }

                if (title) {
                    addContent += "<b>Title: </b>" + (result.childNodes[0].nodeValue) + "<br />";
                    title = false;
                    date = true;
                } else if (date) {
                    addContent += "<b>Date: </b>" + (result.childNodes[0].nodeValue) + "<br />";
                    date = false;
                    content = true;
                } else if (content) {
                    addContent += "<div class='article'><p><b>Content: </b>" + (result.childNodes[0].nodeValue) + "<p></div>";
                    content = false;
                    title = true;
                }
                hr++;
                if (hr % 3 == 0) {
                    addContent += "<hr />";
                }

                result = nodes.iterateNext();
            }
        }
        else if (typeof xml.selectNodes !== 'undefined' && typeof xml.setProperty != 'undefined') {
            // For IE only
            xml.setProperty('SelectionLanguage', 'XPath');
            xml.setProperty('SelectionNamespaces', 'xmlns:p="http://www.familiagrissi.com/posts"');
            var nodes = xml.selectNodes(path);

            var nodes = xml.selectNodes(path);

            for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) { addContent += nodes[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br><hr />"; }
        }

        document.getElementById("loadPathXML").innerHTML = addContent;
        document.getElementById("testing").innerHTML = testing;
    }
```

My most successful attempt so far was when printing only the posts title and filtering it by language:

```
        var language = "es";
        var path = "//p:title[@lang='" + language + "']";
```

But when using this method with the full code the website filters the titles but loads all dates and contents.

I've run out of ideas, so any ideas is very welcome. I'll test it and post the results here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two main problem, not related with the JavaScript.
I was missing the folder name on the first line of code on the .xml file. In bold below.

```
<b:blog xmlns:b="http://www.familiagrissi.com/blog" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.familiagrissi.com/blog/blog.xsd">
```

Also, my logic on the XML file was wrong. I had the following structure:

```
<p:posts xmlns:p="http://www.familiagrissi.com/posts">
    <p:post id="P012">
        <p:title lang="es">Jorge Juan Crespo de la Serna</p:title>
        <p:author>Cristiano Maia</p:author>
        <p:date>2014-10-14</p:date>
        <p:content>Jorge Juan Crespo de la Serna (1887 – 24 julio de 19781 )...</p:content>
    </p:post>

    <p:post id="P011">
        <p:title lang="en">Lorem Ipsu</p:title>
        <p:author>Cristiano Maia</p:author>
        <p:date>2014-10-14</p:date>
        <p:content>Jorge Lorem IpsuLorem IpsuLorem Ipsude 19781 )...</p:content>
    </p:post>
</p:posts>
```

And I was trying to filter all the posts with lang="es", but it wasn't possible being a sibling to the other contents. So I moved the attribute **lang** to the parent element **p:post**.

```
<p:posts xmlns:p="http://www.familiagrissi.com/posts">
    <p:post id="P012" lang="es">
        <p:title>Jorge Juan Crespo de la Serna</p:title>
        <p:author>Cristiano Maia</p:author>
        <p:date>2014-10-14</p:date>
        <p:content>Jorge Juan Crespo de la Serna (1887 – 24 julio de 19781 )...</p:content>
    </p:post>

    <p:post id="P011" lang="en">
        <p:title>Lorem Ipsu</p:title>
        <p:author>Cristiano Maia</p:author>
        <p:date>2014-10-14</p:date>
        <p:content>Jorge Lorem IpsuLorem IpsuLorem Ipsude 19781 )...</p:content>
    </p:post>
</p:posts>
```

Now I can use the following path and it works fine:

```
var path = "//p:post[@lang='" + lang + "']/p:title|//p:post[@lang='" + lang + "']/p:content|//p:post[@lang='" + lang + "']/p:date";
```

Not the cleanest code, but does the job.
Live (22th Jan 2015) example can be found here: http://www.familiagrissi.com/blog/ (but only works properly on Firefox).